# Instrumentation handbook

Tags: resource-recommendations, electrical-engineering, electronics, instrument

Does anyone have any suggestion on a handbook of instrumentation?
In particular [NIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_Instrumentation_Module) instrumentation...
I would like an approach which will explain the techniques and how to use NIM modules.

In particluar I would like an approach from the point of view of the user, not the developer.
For instance, ''what does the "veto" do in a dual timer?'', ''How to use a discriminator for a simple trigger?'' and stuff like that.

Comment: Well, the article you linked to provides a [link to the standard in PDF format](http://www.osti.gov/energycitations/servlets/purl/7120327-MV8wop/7120327.PDF). There isn't a "user's manual" that I know of but most practical experimental texts from the 702-90s say a bit about it. I learned out of Leo *Techniques for Nuclear and Particle Physics Experiments - A How-to Approach*, though annoyingly my copy has been missing for upwards of a year now.

Comment: @dmckee:Thank you very much for your comment! I have already read Leo, but I would like a more experimental approach. Leo just describes some modules but he doesn't say anything about how to use them. As far as the link you provided os concerned, I have also checked and again I would like something from a user's point of view...

Answer (score 0):

A very good but general reference is *Building Scientific Apparatus* by Moore, et al. It should have a few pages devoted to NIM equipment. A better electronics reference *Art of Electronic* by Horowitz and Hill, but they don't discuss NIM (to my knowledge). They do discuss good habits in soldering and making electronics boxes.

If you have the choice, I would try to avoid NIM. I use a lot of homemade NIM modules and I find that the NIM standards are antiquated and problematic for many of our purposes. On the other hand, I don't actually do nuclear physics, so I don't benefit from the available electronics manufactured for NIM.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Although the suggested books are great, they don't meet my criteria. I need a textbook/handbook which will describe the use of NIM module. I need NIM because I am working on detectors...